# Nginx exactly ROOT directive (not anything)

Tags: regex, rest, nginx

I have a RESTful server. I serve my static files with Nginx. I want the root url ( www.website.com, www.website.com/ ) to point to a static html file, and **EVERY** other request to be redirected to my RESTful server. What I have:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias   "some location";
    }

    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias   "some location";
    }
```

What I need: a directive that redirects only the Root URL (not everything like `/`).

Answer (score 1):

Nginx [`location` directive](http://nginx.org/r/location) has `=` modifier for that.

```
location = / {
    # only request to '/' gets here
}
location / {
    # all other goes here
}
```